# Kill Process, containing an infinite loop, clearly on multiple os

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, multiprocessing, python-unittest

I have a Python3 program, which shall be tested with linux and windows with Python 3.6+.

For thos testenviroment is a TestServer needed which shall run in the Background as Process (from multiprocessing), while the tests are running. The tests are running with unittests.

The TestServer process(called mainloop) looks like this:

```
def mainloop(somearg):
    server = mylib.server.Server()
    # some initialisation stuff
    server.start()
    while True: # How to break/handle this if process shall be killed?
        while True:  # How to break/handle this if process shall be killed?
            event = server.get_event()
            if event:
                logger.info(event)
            else:
                break
        time.sleep(1)
    server.stop() # never been reached
    server.cleanup()  # never been reached
```

My setUpClass looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from mylib import mainloop

# some other stuff

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.process = Process(target=mainloop)
    cls.process.start()
    time.sleep(2) # wait for server to start

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    kill(cls.process.pid,1)
```

Questions:

1. How can I handle that if "mainloop" shall be killed, it is able to stop and is cleaned up a proper way?
2. How can I manage that for windows and linux systems?
3. What is best practice for such testing purposes (handle multiple os and test on each multiple python versions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are basically 2 main ways you can shut your server down properly.

1. send a special message to the server that tells him he should shut down
2. kill the process the server runs on

it seems that your code uses the latter, ill focus on that.
you do send a signal for the server process to stop by using the `os.kill` function which is great!

but you need to make a few adjustments to your code so it would work like you want.
first lets define what want:

1. function `tearDownClass` would send a signal to the server to stop
2. server would receive that signal and exit gracefully

lets make the adjustments:
1.

```
import signal  # built-in library for signals
import os
...

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    # this is very uncomfortable but windows makes it hard because they have
    # their own signals
    send_signal = signal.SIGINT if os.name == "posix" else signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
    kill(cls.process.pid,send_signal)
```

2. now we need to take care of handling what happens when a signal comes to the process

```
def mainloop(somearg):
    server = mylib.server.Server()
    # some initialisation stuff
    server.start()

    # defining a callback for cleanup
    def gracfull_cleanup():
        server.stop()
        server.cleanup()

    # again registering the proper signals to the OS
    receiving_signal = signal.SIGINT if os.name == "posix" else signal.CTRL_C_EVENT
    signal.signal(receiving_signal, gracfull_cleanup)

    while True: # How to break/handle this if process shall be killed?
        while True:  # How to break/handle this if process shall be killed?
            event = server.get_event()
            if event:
                logger.info(event)
            else:
                break
        time.sleep(1)
    server.stop() # never been reached
    server.cleanup()  # never been reached
```

and that should do the trick.
note that now once you send a signal, your handler will go to work and do the cleanup for you.

*final note!*
i am not using windows so i cant test it, if the signal is not working try SIGILL

Comment: This looks understandable. So I will have to juggle everytime with if/elses in any os case and perhaps with python versions as well?

Comment: That would work on any python 3.6+ like you stated on the question.  That if/else is enough because all *nix OS would return 'posix', and windows does not (that is, with regards to the `os.name` property).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, just like you can use `kill` to kill your server process.

You can send a signal to it. And if your server process has register a signal handler. Then it could exit gracefully.

But that only work in Unix-like system(Some signals do not be implement in Windows). If you want your program work on Windows/Unix-like system, you could extend the `signal` mechanism to more general `RPC`.

For example, listen a port with TCP socket. When you want to close from outside, send it a message.

Comment: How can I integrate a signal handler to the mainloop Process? And how shall/can extend the signal mechanism to more general RPC (I know what it is and does, but never programmed myself)? Is there a Python-BuildIn way?